# ProxyCommand without socat, nc or Bash's TCP redirection?

Tags: ssh, io-redirection, proxy

`ssh_config`'s `ProxyCommand` allows to establish some connection to a proxy prior to establishing the connection to the actual target machine.

Simple question: how can I leverage the dynamic or SOCKS proxy functionality *built into `ssh`* such that I don't have to rely on `nc` or `socat` to be installed and TCP redirection to be compiled into the installed Bash?

I have literally only found examples of the above all over the web.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `ssh` on the proxy side is new enough (>= OpenSSH 5.4), you can use its `-W` option which works similar than `nc`. Add to the corresponding entry in your `.ssh/config` file:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p PROXYHOST
```

Example:

```
Host TARGETHOST
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p PROXYHOST
  HostName 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: if the `PROXYHOST` takes a different user than `TARGETHOST`, you can specify it at the end of `ProxyCommand` with `-l <proxyuser>`. And for the `TARGETHOST` you specify it on a different line with `User <targetuser>`